# What style to choose MLA or APA?

Tags: writing-style, methodology

I will be writing an essay about Brexit and I am confused on which style of writing to use.

Comment: Asuming this is a coursework, this will 100% depend on the choice of your teacher. You should ask him. There's nothing much the people here can do for you beyond some general listing of + and - things without further information.

Comment: In any case, I don't think there are any Brexit-related reasons to prefer one style or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Unless explicitly stated by your instructor, I believe you should be free to use any. Just for the context about what you might find in the relevant literature, the MLA is generally used in the field of arts and humanities, whereas APA is mostly used in psychology and other social science. However, they **are** used across the fields too.